# minimize memory use in c

Tags: c

I am doing this program its working correctly but the only problem is that when value of int C is 8 digit number it uses 320kib memory,how can i minimize memory use in this program?

**Here is my code**
**1<=Q<=pow(10,5)**
**1<=C<=pow(10,7)**

**C programe**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Stack{
int info;
struct Stack *next;
};

typedef struct Stack node;
node *start=NULL,*last,*neu;
```

**push()**

```
void push(int x)
{
    neu = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    neu->info = x;
    neu->next = NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start = last = neu;
    }
    else
    {
        neu->next = last;
        last = neu;
    }

}
```

**pop()**

```
void pop()            //updated
{   node *temp;      //Updated
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("No Food\n");
    }
    else
    {   
        printf("%d\n",last->info);
        temp = last;
        last = last->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

**main()**

```
int main()
{   
    int Q,type;
    int C;
    scanf("%d",&Q);
    while(Q!=0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&type);

        if(type == 1)
        {
            pop();
        }

        if(type == 2)
        {
            scanf("%d",&C);
            push(C);
        }
        Q--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you `pop` from the stack, you don't `free` the top `node` pointer; instead you just discard it, which causes a memory leak. Try this: `node* tmp = last; last = last->next; free(tmp);`.

Comment: i changed my code but still it is taking same amount of memory

Comment: I can see for Q how it influences memory consumption, not for C however.

Comment: `int pop()` lacks return values.  This implies not using a fully enable compiler.  Enable all warnings.

Comment: It's not `int* tmp`, it's `node* tmp`. And if that is the case, then that would be an internal implementation detail of `malloc / free`. You could try to *pool* the freed nodes by adding them to a separate list; when you try to allocate more nodes, first check if that list is empty - if not then pop a node off it, else malloc a new one.

Comment: Maximum 100000*sizeof(int32_t) required.

Comment: i tried to make it void pop() but it doesn't help

Comment: Pop return value (declared but not implemented, as mentioned by @chux) gets ignored.

Comment: i changed my code,but still i have same problem, free in not working why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since you don't seem to understand our comments, I'm just going to implement what I said here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Stack {
    int info;
    struct Stack * next;
} node, *pnode;

pnode   top  = NULL,    // you only need the top pointer for a stack
        pool = NULL;    // the "pool" I mentioned

// allocate a new node
pnode get_new()
{
    if (pool == NULL)
        return malloc(sizeof(node));
    pnode tmp = pool;
    pool = pool->next;
    return tmp;
}

// push operation
int push(int x)
{
    pnode new = get_new();
    if (new == NULL) // in case malloc fails
        return 0;
    new->info = x;
    new->next = top;
    top = new;
    return 1;
}

// pop operation
pnode pop()
{
    if (top == NULL)
        return NULL;
    pnode tmp = top;
    top = top->next;
    tmp->next = pool;
    pool = tmp;
    return tmp;
}

// factored out the printf stuff from your original pop
// since they are irrelevant to stack operations
void pop_orig()
{
    pnode popped = pop();
    if (pnode == NULL)
        printf("No Food\n");
    else
        printf("%d\n", popped->info);
}

int main()
{   
    int Q, C, type;

    scanf("%d", &Q);

    while (Q > 0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&type);

        if (type == 1)
        {
            pop_orig();
        }
        else
        if (type == 2)
        {
            scanf("%d", &C);  
            if (push(C) == 0) {
                printf("malloc failed - no memory left\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        Q--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you explain me get_new()

Comment: @VikasGautam it allocates a new node to put on the stack; as I said before it first checks if there are any previously popped nodes available in `pool`; if not then it `malloc`s a new node

Comment: `void pop_orig()` doesn't really match `if (pop_orig() == 0)` :-(

Comment: @ingoleonhardt ah yes sorry, that was meant for `push`